# In Python, how can I keep track of my position in a .csv file, in the case of an exception, during a for loop that reads each line?

Tags: python, csv, try-catch

I am making a few thousand web requests, but I can't complete it all at once. How can I save my position, possibly using `try` and `except`, in the case of a `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`? I would like to use `time.sleep` for five minutes, or something when the error occurs, and continue where it left off. I am not sure how to continue where I left off. I considered making a list and then popping elements from it, but that seems cumbersome. Any suggestions?

Here's the meat of my code:

```
with open('csvlist.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        retrieveAdd(row[0])
```

Where `retrieveAdd` makes the web request and adds some data to a database. I tried sleeping after every 100 requests (below) but it didn't work.

```
with open('csvlist.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        retrieveAdd(row[0])
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            time.sleep(180)
```

Comment: I don't see why popping elements from a list could be cumbersome.

Comment: As a side note, instead of keeping a manual `count` variable, just do `for count, row in enumerate(reader):`.

Comment: As a side note, randomly adding sleeps rarely helps a problem. Taking a program that worked 20% of the time and making it work 30% of the time (and take twice as long to do so) is rarely considered a successful fix. If you know there's some rate threshold you have to stay below (N requests/second or /hour or whatever), that's a different story, and `sleep` is a great way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the "retry after 5 minutes" operation in a function?

```
def retrieveAddSafe(data, repeat=5):
    """ Attempts to retrieve `data`, swallowing HTTPErrors `repeat` times before
    throwing"""
    for _ in xrange(repeat - 1):
        try:
            return retrieveAdd(data)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            time.sleep(5 * 60)

    # if it fails after `repeat` times, allow the error to be raised
    return retrieveAdd(data)

with open('csvlist.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for count, row in enumerate(reader):
        retrieveAddSafe(row[0])
```

Comment: I'm sure either of the two methods would have worked great, but I like the concept of "wrapping it in a function", and this was super easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The file object and `csv.reader` object together are already keeping track of their position, so if you just handle the exception somewhere inside that `with` statement, you can just loop `for row in reader:` again and it will pick up where it left off.

For a really stupid example:

```
with open('csvlist.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    ireader = enumerate(reader)
    try:
        for i, row in ireader:
            print('Read row #{}'.format(i))
            if i == 10:
                raise ValueError("I don't like the 10th row")
    except Exception as e:
        print('Raised {}'.format(e))
    for i, row in ireader:
        print('Read row #{}'.format(i))
```

(In case it isn't obvious: if a file is resumable, and a `csv.reader` wrapped around that file is resumable, so is an `enumerate` wrapped around that `csv.reader`, as pointed out by Eric in the comments.)

---

And of course if you can handle the exception inside the `for` loop, you don't even need this:

```
with open('csvlist.csv', 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        try:
            print('Read row #{}'.format(i))
            if i == 10:
                raise ValueError("I don't like the 10th row")
        except Exception as e:
            print('Raised {}'.format(e))
```

And in your case, I don't see any reason why you couldn't do that.

---

If you really need to handle the exception at a higher level, the only guaranteed safe solution is to remember how many rows in you were and skip that many rows… but using the `tell` and `seek` methods works with every Python I have access to, and is likely to be safe with any reasonable implementation of the `csv` module. So, each time through the loop, stash `data.tell()` in a variable that will be accessible in the `except`, and then you can re-open the file, `data.seek(stash)`, and re-create the `reader`. (You can even put `stash` in a text file/pickle/database/whatever, so you can quit the process and pick up where you left off.)

Comment: You'd do better to just store the `enumerate` iterator here, rather than reconstructing a new one